# Problems using fprintf

Tags: c

Here is what my file open look like:

```
FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "a+");
```

I read my value that I want to get from the PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER enviromental variable.

```
char env;
env = getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");
printf("\nA The processor identifier is: %s\n\n", env);
```

The printf prints it out fine. Now I want to append it to the end of my file with:

```
fprintf(f, "%s", env);
```

But it doesn't really do the job. What could be the issue? Do I have to use a loop?

Comment: No..  '%s' is the wrong format specifier for a char.

Comment: 'The printf prints it out fine' - one kind of UB is appearing to work.

Comment: Please read [the manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/). `%s` is for null-terminated strings, which a char is not. `%c` is for char.

Comment: It doesn't work either way. It's really frustrating.
Edit: I found a solution. Apparently with a+ you have to rewind the whole file.

Comment: `char env;
env = getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");` -- Are you sure that's your actual code? That shouldn't even compile. `env` should be a `char*`, not a `char`. It's important to include your actual (copy-and-pasted) code in the question.

Comment: `env` should be declared as `char*`, not `char`.

Comment: You guys are right. It's a char *.

Comment: When you edit your original question with the suggested bug fixes, the question becomes malformed and the comments offered by others then make no sense. It is perfectly okay, to append to your question with the changes, but you should leave the original intact

Answer (score 2):

The function `getenv` is defined as `char *getenv(const char *name);` in stdlib.h, also make sure check if getenv successfully find the environment variable before writing to the file:

```
char *env;
env = getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");
if (env != NULL) {
    printf("\nA The processor identifier is: %s\n", env);

    fprintf(f, "%s", env);
}
```

Comment: You might need something like fprintf(f, "%s\n", env ) or a call to fflush() ; to assure your string gets output.

Comment: As for `fprintf(f, "%s\n", env);`, it can only be known by the op since they result different files. But I concur fflush would be ok.